# Magento 2 PWA remove .html Prefix

Tags: pwa, magento2.3.5, pwa-studio

How can I remove .html prefix from Venia Concept Product URL Suffix and Category URL Suffix as my magento instance doesn't have an sufix set and I thought it would pick it up from the settings but it looks like it isn't ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v found out that looks like it's hard coded in `../pwa-studio/packages/venia-ui/lib/components/CategoryTree/categoryLeaf.js`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { func, shape, string } from 'prop-types';
import { useCategoryLeaf } from '@magento/peregrine/lib/talons/CategoryTree';

import { mergeClasses } from '../../classify';
import { Link, resourceUrl } from '../../drivers';
import defaultClasses from './categoryLeaf.css';

const suffix = '.html';

const Leaf = props => {
    const { category, onNavigate } = props;
    const { name, url_path } = category;
    const classes = mergeClasses(defaultClasses, props.classes);
    const { handleClick } = useCategoryLeaf({ onNavigate });
    const destination = resourceUrl(`/${url_path}${suffix}`);

    return (
        <li className={classes.root}>
            <Link
                className={classes.target}
                to={destination}
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                <span className={classes.text}>{name}</span>
            </Link>
        </li>
    );
};

export default Leaf;

Leaf.propTypes = {
    category: shape({
        name: string.isRequired,
        url_path: string.isRequired
    }).isRequired,
    classes: shape({
        root: string,
        target: string,
        text: string
    }),
    onNavigate: func.isRequired
};
```

And for product urls they are in :`../pwa-studio/packages/venia-ui/lib/components/Gallery/item.js` This one has a TODO so I'm assuming it will come from magento instance settings:

```
...
// TODO: get productUrlSuffix from graphql when it is ready
const productUrlSuffix = '.html';
...
```

I Do think this really should be using settings of the Magento instance it connected to!